# dropdown OnSelectedIndexChanged my url change?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm facing a problem :

I have one drop down list in which select my size then prize change according to size:

but my url is changes. Why? please solve this problem:

first time when I click product, it shows url like this:

http://localhost:7686/derewala/_op

when I select value from dropdown, url changes like this:

http://localhost:7686/derewala/_op?name=op

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_size" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_size_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Please provide OnSelectedIndexChanged source code

Comment: @devendra show some code

Comment: string size = ddl_size.SelectedValue;

        if (ddl_size.SelectedValue != "")
        {
            Session["Image_Id"] = int.Parse(Image_Id.Value);           
            Objadmin.TagName = Session["tagname"].ToString();           
            Objadmin.Size_Id = int.Parse(ddl_size.SelectedValue);          
            DataSet ds = Objadmin.ProductOperations();
            if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count != 0)
            {
               
          }
        }

Comment: Can you give us this method ddl_size_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: We can't see your localhost site!

Comment: @devendra....try removing the query string from the url on page load after the OnSelectedChanged has been activated....you can do this either from the c# code behind or the javascript end.....if you'd like i can provide you with some links......just say the word......

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if you used in php:

```
<select name="filterby" onchange="myFunction()" id="filterby">
  <option value="ov">ov</option>
  <option value="op">op</option>
  <option value="ob">ob</option>
</select>
```

You javascript code is:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("filterby").value;
     window.location= 'localhost/darewala/?filterby="+x;
}
</script>
```